# Unity - Exposing a function to the inspector

Tags: unity, c#, events, editors

I wish to expose a script's function to the inspector, but I have no clue how to. I found something about `Invoke()` which was a start, but it isn't clear how to finish.

My code for the class:

```
 [System.Serializable]
     class MoveAction : UnityEvent<MonoBehaviour>, IUIAnimationEvent
     {
         #region Move
         public MoveAction()
         {

         }
         //to ensure only one mover coroutine can be active.
         IEnumerator moveRoutine = null;
         #region Solution 2: using fields and not parameters
         Transform from;
         Transform to;
         float overTime;
         public delegate void UIchain(MonoBehaviour mono);
         public event UIchain NEXT_FUNCTION;

         public MoveAction(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime, IUIAnimationEvent chain)
         {
             this.from = from;
             this.to = to;
             this.overTime = overTime;

         }
         public void Move(MonoBehaviour mono)
         {
             if (moveRoutine != null)
             {
                 mono.StopCoroutine(moveRoutine);
             }
             moveRoutine = _Move(from, to, overTime, mono);
             mono.StartCoroutine(moveRoutine);
             Invoke(mono);
         }
         IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime, MonoBehaviour mono)
         {
             Vector2 original = from.position;
             float timer = 0.0f;
             while (timer < overTime)
             {
                 float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
                 from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
                 timer += Time.deltaTime;
                 yield return null;
             }
             if(NEXT_FUNCTION != null)
             {
                 NEXT_FUNCTION(mono);
             }
         }
```

This is a lot of code, but the interesting part is the `Move(MonoBehaviour mono)` function. I want to expose that to the editor. How?

**EDIT:**

Something like this would be preferable:

[image]

Comment: What would this look like when exposed to the editor? Are you envisioning a button in the Inspector that the user presses to execute the function? How would the argument be selected? Or do you have a different workflow in mind? Have you read about creating custom Inspector scripts?

Comment: I have read about custom editors, but I hope I don't need those to make this work. 
I made a UI animations addon but I still need a few lines of code to make it work (= instantiate the given class, call a function and so on). 
I need to add a list of functions with the parameters and it will execute them one by one (this chaining is already solved, but works only through code). @DMGregory I edited the question with an image.

Comment: The screenshot you added looks like what you get audomatically when you add a public UnityEvent to your MonoBehaviour - [see this answer for an example of setting this up](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132957/39518).

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. You could convert that comment to answer so I can accept/upvote.

Comment: One more thing. Can I do that as an array of different classes? @DMGregory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is the Unity Event class. See this example below. This will appear in the editor exactly like your screenshot.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Collections;

public class InvokeOnAwake : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEvent invokeMethod;//set in editor

    void Awake(){
        invokeMethod.Invoke();
    }

}
```